# css div margin moving entire div instead of content

Tags: css, html, margin

i have:

HTML

```
<div id="container"><div id="left"><div class="box">blahblah</div></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.box  {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 50px;
    background:url(box.png) no-repeat } 
#container{
    width:100%;
}
#left{
    float:left;
    width: 260px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

When i add `margin: 25px;` to the .box class, it moves the entire box div across the page.
What should i do in order to margin the content (blahblah) within the div (.box)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you're simply looking for `padding: 25px;` instead - this adds space *inside* the box dimensions or *around* the content box and within the border edge

Here is a simple model to help visualize the box model:

http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/4949/boxdim.png

Take a look at the **Box Model** section in the CSS 2.1 Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html to learn more

Answer (score 1):

You must consider the fact that CSS uses a "box model"

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Margins are for external space limitations whereas padding is used for internal.

Comment: In the future, try to avoid using w3schools (less credible source) when you can link to the actual w3 specification.

Comment: No offense to the OP, but I believe w3schools would be more beneficial than the documentation for questions like these as he is clearly new to css.  At any rate he's got both links in these two answers now.  Thanks for the suggestion though, I will consider it moving forward.